# Python fabric library hide imports decorated by @task from namespace

Tags: python, fabric

I have both a @task decorator on a function and the requirement to pull that function into another module.

Whenever I import this function it pollutes the modules namespace with the same task.

Presumably this is simply because of the @task decorator. Is there a way around this?

Appreciate any help

I think the **init**.py and **all** approach is probably a nice one

Comment: Can't you do <code>from fabric import task as fab_task</code> ?